# Loop through specific range using AWK

Tags: csv, awk

I have a csv file with multiple sections in a sheet. 
I want to loop through a specific range only. Say loop through row 10 to 100.

My below code so far loops through the whole sheet.

```
awk -v val1='Batch File Name' -F ',' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==val1) {print i} }' "$FILES"
```

Comment: elaborate your question: **row** or **column**?

Answer (score 2):

To only match some rows you can use the `begin pattern,end pattern` construct

```
NR==10,NR==100 { action}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be faster if your file is long

```
awk -F, -v val1='Batch File Name' 'NR>100{exit} 
           NR>=10{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==val1) print i} files
```